# UIButton not working in UITableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

[image]Have `UITableviewcell` --> inside which i have 4 different UIView and 3 of the views has UIButtons. I want to make `UIButton` clickable. For the first time the buttons are clickable but when i go to next screen and come back, the buttons don't work. Please let me know how to implement this? Thanks!

PHMyTripView *tripsView=[[PHMyTripView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, self.frame.size.width-20, cell.frame.size.height)];

```
                         tripsView.onBaggageClick = ^{
                             [weakSelf handleBaggagePurchaseTapped];
                         };

                         if ([data count]>0) {
                             [tripsView fillTripData:[data firstObject]];
                             [tripsView showAncillaries:self.predictiveManager.upcomingCDAirBookingInfo];
                         }
                         [cell bringSubviewToFront:tripsView.bagsButton];
                         [cell.viewPlaceHolder addSubview:tripsView];
```

Comment: show the whole code

Comment: I have updated the code snippet. None of the answers really helped. I did change the background color of button to see its frame everything is fine. But its just not clickable instead it goes to didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Let me know for any clarifications. Thanks all for your response. Looking forward to the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the cells are reusable and if you go to another screen the button may kinda mess round into different cell in UI or functionally.

The way to solve this is to add tag. You can define cell.tag = indexPath.row * 10 or so.

Then when draw the button, you check the condition, if cell.tag == ?, then add your button.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your response but they din't work in my case. 
Here is the answer. Since the UITableview was reloading when it comes back to the screen.The frames were mis placed and Hence the button was not able to click.

Used this one line code which worked fine.

self.tripsView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Answer (score 0):

You should turn off `delaysContentTouches` on each `UITableView` subview, which is an instance of `UIScrollView` class. 
Subclass `UITableView` and override `initWithFrame` method:

.h file

```
@interface NoDelaysOnTouchTableView : UITableView

@end
```

And .m file

```
#import "NoDelaysOnTouchTableView.h"

@implementation NoDelaysOnTouchTableView

- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame: frame];

    if (self) {
        for (id view in self.subviews) {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString: @"UITableViewWrapperView"]) {
                if ([view isKindOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]) {
                    // turn OFF delaysContentTouches in the hidden subview
                    UIScrollView* scroll = (UIScrollView*)view;
                    scroll.delaysContentTouches = NO;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Next - use this subclass (create an instance of `NoDelaysOnTouchTableView`) to be able to press `UIButton` immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the causes would be multiples.
You can try:

- check the constraints for each button in your cell
- in cellForRow you can do addTarget: for each button with relative     @selector and in this method check the object (datasource) associated to button.
- do not use addSubView in your cell, instead use a Xib (or define your cell in a storyboard within tableView) so you can set the constraints.

I Hope, i've helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically about this issue, but for some people it may be the case.Try to add subviews in `contentView` of the cell.
Instead of `addSubview(textField)` use `contentView.addSubview(textField)`